# Код не работает в IE, в Chrome все нормально

Tags: html, jquery, internet-explorer, кроссбраузерность

Хочу сделать на сайте выбор города, чтобы все записывалось в куки и телефоны выдавались те в котором городе находится пользователь:

```js
//$.cookie("gorod", null);
//Функция selected выбырает элемент основываясь на данных из куки
$(function() {

function mSelect() {
    var attr = $.cookie("gorod");
    $("#" + attr + "").attr('selected', 'selected');

}
//Функция возвращает значение выбранного города
function getGorod() {
    var gorod = $("select#goroda").val();
    return gorod;
};
//alert(getGorod());
//Функция отправляет куки со значением города 
function setCookie() {
    var gorod = getGorod();
    $.cookie("gorod", gorod);
}

//Функция принимает параметр либо из куки либо из selecta в зависимости от наличия кук 
function phones(val) {
    switch (val) {
        case "Ast":
            $("p#phone").html('+7 (7172) 37-91-44 </br>  +7(7172) 49 09 67 ');
            $.cookie("gorod", "Ast");
            mSelect();
            break;
        case "Alm":
            $("p#phone").html('+7 (727) 390-26-60 <br> +7 (707) 807 00 20 ');
            $.cookie("gorod", "Alm");
            mSelect();
            break;
        case "Shym":
            $("p#phone").html('Телефон Шымкента');
            $.cookie("gorod", "Shym");
            mSelect();
            break;
        case "Pav":
            $("p#phone").html('Телефон Павлодара');
            $.cookie("gorod", "Pav");
            mSelect();
            break;
    }
}
//Функция  следит за изменениями селекта и кажды раз отправляет параметр в функцию phones
function changeMain() {
    $("#goroda").change(function() {
        var val = getGorod();
        phones(val);
    });
}
//alert($.cookie("gorod"));
//Функция проверяющая наличие кук
function existCookie() {
    if ($.cookie("gorod") != "null") {
        //если куки не пустой то выводим соответствующие данные 
        var val = $.cookie("gorod");
        phones(val);
        changeMain();
    } else {
        //если куки пустой то создаем куки
        $("p#phone").text('Телефон Алматы');
        changeMain();
    }
}
existCookie();


});
```

```html
<body>
<select name="viborGoroda" id="goroda">
  <option value="0">Выбери свой город</option>
  <option id="Alm" value="Alm">Алматы</option>
  <option id="Ast" value="Ast">Астана</option>
  <option id="Shym" value="Shym">Шымкент</option>
  <option id="Pav" value="Pav">Павлодара</option>
 </select>
<p id="phone"></p>
```

Также выложил код на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8h43uq7p/).

Во всех, кроме IE - работает. В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: У меня работает - IE11

Comment: что именно не работает? как не работает? пишет ошибку в консоли? просто ничего не делает? делает что-то не то?

Comment: IE различных версий ну очень отличается, указывайте версию. Ну и разумеется ошибку в консоли и что конкретно не работает.

Comment: А разве майкрософт не прекратили его поддержку? ИЕ мертв.

Comment: @JoyDIR - Давайте скажем это пользователям, которые им пользуются.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса

Comment: @Doofy [а вам пока нельзя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) :) На отметке 3000 станет можно.